# laravel snaapy This site can’t be reached?

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-5.4, laravel-snappy

I'm using laravel-snappy tool for pdf making. its all working fine but suddenly. its throwing
```

```
    This site can’t be reached
    The webpage at https://gpschool.dev/acadmic/2/t_c_print might be temporarilydown or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

`my laravel config for snappy.php`

return array(

```
'pdf' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),
),
'image' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe"',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),
),
```

);
```
i don't know what happened.
thanks

Comment: Please check the Laravel log file at storage/logs/laravel.log and include the error message in your question.

Comment: ya its fine i include laravel mix file in print.blade.php and i removed that and write css code within the page and this is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I just recently having this trouble and fix the pr,

for me when I tried to open the 'wkhtmltoimage.exe' it throw missing .dll, so I just install the missing .dll using microsoft visual c++ 2013.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

it might be because of ssl don't use any secure script or css use only non ssl